# Unknown provider: e from AngularJS/Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependency-injection, angularjs

I am extending a Rails gem that generates AngularJS-style scaffolding for Rails apps, see 
https://github.com/explainer/angularjs_scaffold.  I have added CoffeeScript language support to a fork from https://github.com/patcito/angularjs_scaffold.

I am getting the error mentioned in the title when I attempt to deploy in production mode, and the javascript code gets minified and obfuscated by the rails asset pipeline.  I have read the  "Note on minification" at http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 and have used the 'array' design pattern mentioned there, but the app still breaks.

The scaffolding generates 2 app-level angular controllers, a dummy WelcomeCtrl, and a CsrfCtrl to handle security tokens.  For each model, 4 REST-style controllers are generated, index, show, create, edit.

I am stumped.  I am requesting that some good person build a small rails app, with one simple model, say

```
rails g scaffold Todo body:string, done:boolean
```

Please include my gem in the :development group in the Gemfile

```
gem 'angularjs_scaffold', git: "git@github.com:explainer/angularjs_scaffold.git"
```

and follow the instructions in the README.md to install the generator and run it against your model,

```
rails g angularjs:install --language=javascript

rails g angularjs:scaffold Todos
```

Then, inspect the files added to the app/javascripts folder:

- csrf_controller.js
- todos.js
- todos_controller.js
- welcome_controller.js

and see if you can see where I am not handling the angularjs dependency injection requirements correctly.

I really appreciate any and all help on this matter.

P.S. I added a sample app, Plink, at https://github.com/explainer/plink, so just inspect the files mentioned above and find my bugs or omissions.

I have made the test app public on github, sorry for the oversight.

Comment: The last link is incorrect. Please fix.

Comment: I cannot access your sample app, but a possible cause could be that you are registering your controllers implicitly. Try using $controllerProver.register() to register your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

A good guy found my problem, it was an omission of a single place where explicit dependency injection was required.  I had overlooked it.  Thanks, Jeff.